# Stored procedure is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

My codebehind for delete looks like this:

```
 protected void delete(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {
     sc.connection();
     //string st = "delete";
     int id = Convert.ToInt32(((Label)(GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("lblpro2"))).Text);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("maniputale", sc.con);
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@action", "delete");
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mysid", 6);
     //cmd.Parameters.Add("@action", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value= st;
     //cmd.Parameters.Add("@mysid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

And the stored procedure is:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE maniputale
 (
    @mysid int = null,
    @myproducts nvarchar(20) = null,
    @mydescription varchar(50) = null,
    @myprice int = null,
    @mybrand varchar(20) = null,
    @mymid int = null,
    @action varchar = null
 )
 as
 Begin
     set NOCOUNT ON;

     if @action = 'insert'
     Begin
         Insert into sub_catTbl(products,description,price,brand,mid)
         values(@myproducts,@mydescription,@myprice,@mybrand,@mymid)
     End

     else if @action = 'select'
     Begin
         select * from sub_catTbl
     End

     else if @action = 'update'
     Begin
         update sub_catTbl set products=@myproducts,description = @mydescription,price =@myprice,brand=@mybrand,mid=@mymid
     End

     else if @action = 'delete'
     Begin
         delete from sub_catTbl where  sid=@mysid;
     End

 End
```

But it's not working. It neither shows any change nor shows an error.

*IS there any way to check if the stored procedure is executing just like we have linebreaker to check .cs files?*

Comment: Please provide the full SP source - or make a minimal example that you **have run** that exhibits the problem.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: What type is `@action`? If it is `char(x)` or `nchar(x)` the comparison may fail because `char` and `nchar` pad the content with spaces until `x` is reached.

Comment: @action is varchar.Let me provide a full stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

You can run your SP in SSMS and debug like you would your c# code. However, if you just run it manually it will most likely be failing and you will see an error returned; if your SP is throwing an error it doesn't return to your web application be default.

Here's what you get when debugging:

[image: Example image]

You can step in/out/over etc like any other code - very useful in situations like this.

Comment: I ran in Ssms and SP is good to go.THe codebehind also shows no error.SO where did i go wrong?

Comment: Put a try/catch around your query execution and a break within the catch looking at Excetpion.ToString(). In my experience the web request will just end on an sql error and not report anything. It could be access credentials or similar..?

Comment: Does the query reach the database? Have you tried other operations than delete (insert/updated etc from your SP)?

Comment: NO i have just started learning Sp and its my first try...How di i check if its reaching the database..but i think i have reached the database because i can display data from database with a gridview which is binded in page_load().

Comment: Use SQL Profiler which is built into SSMS (from the tools menu)

Comment: Does the changes occur in database table after executing stored proc ?

Comment: NO database table is still the same.